# Using SizeTransition widget

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I want to use SizeTransition widget for just an image not for page. It will be my loading page and while loading the application app symbol will be displayed with a size transition.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizeTransition-class.html

I want my logo with this effect in the link. However there is not enough source for me to learn about that widget. Can you please give me an example? I tried something like this but it;s not working.

```
class _AnimTestState extends State<AnimTest>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizeTransition(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/appLogo.png'),
        sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          parent: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all give the controller a duration, either in the constructor like this:

```
controller = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
```

or anywhere before calling `controller.forward()` like this:

```
controller.duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
```

And last and most important thing, you need to start the animation by calling

```
controller.forward();
```

Comment: With controller.forward(from: 0); this solution works.

Answer (score 4):

```
class _AnimTestState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    )..repeat(reverse: true); // automatically animation will be started
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizeTransition(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/appLogo.png'),
        sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          parent: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use `_controller.forward()` or `_controller.reverse()` in a button press if you don't want it to run automatically like I did.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ryosuke's answer (adding `controller.forward()`, be careful not to do this in `build()` other than for testing purposes), in order to achieve the effect displayed on the page you linked, you might want to consider

1. centering your `SizeTransition` widget by wrapping it in a `Center()` widget
2. specifying the transition axis by adding `axisAlignment: -0.5` to your `SizeTransition` widget (see https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizeTransition/axisAlignment.html for details on why).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  controller.forward();
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: SizeTransition(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/appLogo.png'),
        axisAlignment: -0.5,
        sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          parent: controller,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: controller.forward() shouldn't be inside build.

Comment: You're absolutely right. What's a better place for it in a demo snippet?

Comment: Yeah for sake of demo anything works. I was just saying that its not a goof practice.